# How to open Port 80 for App services inside Virtual Private Network

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I am new to Azure. I have created few App services and added into one Resource group. Then created Virtual private network and added App services into the VNet. I want to give public access to few App services which are added into Vnet. 
Please suggest how to open port 80 to give public access the App services from Vnet.

Comment: How did you add your app into a VNet? with VNET integration or ASE? 
VNET integration is a feature which let your web app securely access resources available in or through your Azure VNET, NOT access your app from the VNET! If you use ASE, you can just need to add inbound rules on 80 port on the NSG of the VNET.

Comment: I have added with Vnet Integration. But actually i want is I have 10 App services.I want Few Apps services should be accessible publicly and other stay private should not be able to access publicly. I just followed the tutorials as given by Microsoft to create Vnet Security group etc. Can you please suggest ASE is best way to do that?

Comment: With Vnet integration, you cannot achieve this. Only ASE can do this.

Comment: Hi, Any helpful link to use ASE for the above described scenario. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Harpal , you can refer to this doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro

Answer (score 0):

You could open port 80 via **azure portal**.

1.Create a **Network Security Group**

2.Create an inbound rule allowing traffic

3.Associate the Network Security Group with the VM network interface or subnet

For more details, refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal).

Comment: Thanks But i will go with ASE approach.